# Dictionaries.app only has Wikipedia on High Sierra

Tags: dictionary, high-sierra

I have installed High Sierra 10.13 today over the top of a working 10.12.6 installation.

I have previously used the dictionaries app for the thesaurus and other dictionaries. Upon opening the dictionary app, and going to preferences I can see that only Wikipedia is available.

It seems that it is supposed to download the dictionaries, but it doesn't.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem as jakethedog, only Wikipedia showing! Looked through potential blocking of outgoing calls by Little Snitch. When I removed blocking of nsurlsessiond I got all this other dictionaries also.

Answer to Allan below: Well this is relevant only if you use software Little Snitch for privacy purposes to block outgoing calls from different software https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html
Sometimes one blocks outgoing calls with unexpected consequences. In my case I blocked Apple process *nsurlsession* from "calling home" since it is not entirely clear what info this process transmits to Apple. Apparently it also blocked discovery of these dictionaries. Little Snitch users will understand, for others it is not really relevant.

Comment: How did you do that?  It's helpful if you explain the steps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same installation as yours - I just selected a word and then looked up for it - the OS open the Preference dialog as in your picture, and then you I was waiting for automatic updating the configurations (a progress bar will be opened in the lower left side of the Preference dialog during configuration). Be sure you have an active internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed if I do a lookup, it will give me the option to "Configure Dictionaries" but then only shows the wikipedia option. I have fast internet. I suppose apple's server could be overloaded on launch day...

Comment: I have done nothing else than what I said in response above. The configuration update started automatically...